# Check saved entry is a brand new entry

Tags: entries, plugins, entry

I have a plugin using the onBeforeSaveEntry event. Is there a simple way to check if the entry being saved is a brand new entry i.e. Add New Entry or if it currently exists and is just being updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to check for this like so:

```
if($params['isNewEntry'])
{
 // The entry is new
{
else
{
 // The entry is being updated
{
```

See here in the docs: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onBeforeSaveEntry

Comment: Cheers @AlecRitson perfect